# Hadoop-Hive-HBase Advice for Web Analytics

Tags: java, hadoop, analytics, hbase, hive

The team I work on is fortunate enough to have management that recognizes the need to enhance our skills and learn new technologies.  As a result, whenever we have a little downtime between major projects, we are encouraged to use that time to stretch our minds a bit and learn something new.  We often tackle a large research project as a team so that everyone benefits from the knowledge.  For example, we built a spec-compliant Kerberos authentication server to get familiar with the ins and outs of the protocol.  We wrote our own webserver to learn about efficient design strategies for networked applications.

Recently, we've been very curious about Map-Reduce, specifically Hadoop and the various supporting components (HBase, HDFS, Pig, Hive, etc.).  To learn a bit more about it, we would like to write a web analytics service.  It will use Javascript page tagging to gather the metrics, and Hadoop and *something* to make analytics and reports available via a web interface.

The non-Hadoop side of the architecture is easy.  A Java servlet will parse the parameters from a Javascript tag (easy enough -- we're a Java shop).  The servlet will then send out a JMS message for asynchronous processing (again, easy).

My question is...  What next?  We've researched things like Hive a bit, and it sounds like a great fit for querying the datastore for the various metrics we're looking for.  But, it's high latency.  We're fortunate enough to be able to drop this onto a website that gets a few million hits per month.  We'd really like to get relatively quick metrics using the web interface for our analytics tool.  Latency is not our friend.  So, what is the best way to accomplish this?  Would it be to run the queries as a scheduled job and then store the results somewhere with lower latency (PostgreSQL, etc.) and retrieve them from there?  If that's the case, where should the component listening for the JMS messages store the data?  Can Hive get its data from HBase directly?  Should we store it in HDFS somewhere and read it in Hive?

Like I said, we're a very technical team and love learning new technologies.  This, though, is way different from anything we've learned before, so we'd like to get a sense of what the "best practices" would be here.  Any advice or opinions you can give are GREATLY appreciated!

**EDIT :**  I thought I'd add some clarification as to what I'm looking for.  I'm seeking advice on architecture and design for a solution such as this.  We'll collect 20-30 different metrics on a site that gets several million page views per month.  This will be a lot of data, and we'd like to be able to get metrics in as close to realtime as possible.  I'm looking for best practices and advice on the architecture of such a solution, because I don't want us to come up with something on our own that is really bad that will leave us thinking we're "Hadoop experts" just because it works.

Comment: That's a lot of words. It's not clear to me what specifically you're asking; as-is the question is likely too broad to fit nicely into the SO format. What kinds of metrics are you trying to support? Why not just start collecting data in HBase and experiment?

Comment: The metrics themselves aren't important.  We'll collect the standard browser type, IP address, etc.  This question is more about the architecture that should be used.  We're looking for best practices so that we don't come up with something stupid that works and think we're Hadoop geniuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive, as you mentioned, has high latency for queries.  It can be pointed at HBase (see https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hbaseintegration.html), but the integration results in HBase having tables that are forced into a mostly-rectangular, relational-like schema that is not optimal for HBase.  Plus, the overhead of doing it is extremely costly- hive queries against hbase are, on my cluster, at least an order of magnitude slower than against plain HDFS files.

One good strategy is to store the raw metrics in HBase or on plain HDFS (Might want to look at Flume if these metrics are coming from log files) and run periodic MapReduce jobs (even every 5 minutes) to create pre-aggregated results that you can store in plain rectangular files that you can query through Hive.  When you are just reading a file and Hive doesn't have to do anything fancy (e.g. sorting, joining, etc), then Hive is actually reasonably low latency- it doesn't run MapReduce, it just streams the file's contents out to you.

Finally, another option is to use something like [Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm) (which runs on Hadoop) to collect and analyze data in real time, and store the results for querying as mentioned above, or storing them in HBase for display through a custom user interface that queries HBase directly.

Comment: I've read a couple of articles about backing Hadoop/Hive with Cassandra.  Do you think this would yield better performance or address the other HBase issues you raised?  Just trying to get a good sense of what our potential options are.

Comment: Cassandra and HBase are roughly equivalent in this regard- they are not 'rectangular' data stores, and so they are not amenable to something like Hive or ODBC, which expects data to be nice and rectangular and "relational".  The main advantage that you get with something like Cassandra or HBase is that 1) you get low-latency data access via the API, and 2) you don't need to worry about managing your own I/O to HDFS- you just write via their public APIs and they handle the I/O.